# How to address "AWS Glue Error: Record larger than the Split size: 67108864"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

I have an AWS Glue ETL Pipeline that uses a "relationalize" job to transform nested JSON files into parquet format. The pipeline has been working well for about two months, with a max JSON file size of around 50 MB. Now, the presence of some much larger files (~500 MB JSON files) causes the pipeline to fail with the following error:

`com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.NonFatalException: Record larger than the Split size: 67108864`

I have searched all over the internet, including stack overflow, for solutions to this problem. I have seen numerous posts talking about the same error, but no accepted solutions. My data engineering experience is limited and any guidance to get my pipeline back up and running would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

In my python script, the line that results in the failure is:

`resolvechoice2 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame=datasource0,choice="make_struct", transformation_ctx="resolvechoice2")`

Comment: Have you tried increasing the DPU's? From here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/best-practices-to-scale-apache-spark-jobs-and-partition-data-with-aws-glue/

AWS Glue jobs that process large splittable datasets with medium (hundreds of megabytes) or large (several gigabytes) file sizes can benefit from horizontal scaling and run faster by adding more AWS Glue workers.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. The original job had 2 DPUs, and I have tried 4 and 6 workers with no success.